# Emailing from SQL Server stored procedure with set-based logic, avoiding cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server, email, stored-procedures, cursor

My IT department has a healthy disdain for cursors, yet I need to iterate through a data set to send emails from SQL Server 2014. What is best practice for doing this using set-based logic?

Comment: You could collect the data into a temp. table and then use cursor for that. That way you wouldn't have a cursor open for the actual data while sending emails -- and I don't see problems using cursor for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you are using Database Mail to send the emails out via SQL Server, in which case, emails are sent by calling the `sp_send_dbmail` stored procedure.

With the exception of emails with the same content that need to be sent to multiple recipients whereby you can just add multiple recipients to the `@recipients`, `@copy_recipients`/`@blind_copy_recipients`, in order to send multiple emails you have to call sp_send_dbmail once per email. Therefore, you need to call it within some form of loop as you can't call the sproc within a set-based query.

Technically, you *could* use a set-based query to generate some sql into a variable which would contain one call to sp_send_dbmail per email to send, and then execute that statement, but that could get a bit messy/less readable.

Comment: Hi Ada, yes, I'll be using sp_send_mail, for sure.